# Javascript get full index of nested object

Tags: javascript

```
const items = [
   { id: 'item1',
     children: [ 
      { id: 'item1-1',
        children: [
          { id: 'item1-1-1' },
          { id: 'item1-1-2' },
          { id: 'item1-1-3'
            children: [
               { id: 'item1-1-3-1'}
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      { id: 'item1-2',
        children: [
          { id: 'item1-2-1' }
        ]
      }
    ]
   },
   { id: 'item2' }
]
```

What I want to is like below,

```
function getFullDepthOfObject(){
  ...
}

getFullIndexOfObject('item1') =====> return '1'
getFullIndexOfObject('item1-2') =====> return '1-2'
getFullIndexOfObject('item1-1-1') =====> return '1-1-1'
getFullIndexOfObject('item1-1-2') =====> return '1-1-2'
getFullIndexOfObject('item2') ===> return '2'
```

I have struggled with this too much time, But I couldn't make it. I think I should stack each of `parent` index, But I don't know how to get its parent. Is there a way to do this?

Not parse of `id` string. Each id has randomic string. The id like `item1-2` is for easier demonstration.

I think my way is too verbose...
I tried like ...

```
// Get Full Index of item1-1


// First, get the target's depth.
var depth = 0;

function getDepthOfId(object, id) {
    var level;
    if (object.id === id) return 1;
    object.children && object.children.some(o => level = getDepthOfId(o, id));
    return level && level + 1;
}

depth = getDepthOfId(items[0], 'item1-1');
console.log('depth === ', depth)


// Then, iterate recursively with length of depth.

var indexStacks = [];


function getNestedIndexOfId(obj, id, index) {
    if (obj.id === id) {
        indexStacks = [index, ...indexStacks]
        return index;
    }

    if (obj.children) {
        depth++;
        obj.children.map((child, i) => {
            getNestedIndexOfId(child, id, i)
        })
    }
}

// I can get the inner index, but I can't get its parent id.
// I don't know how to this..

function getParentId(obj, id){
    // ...?
    var parentId;
    return parentId;
}

for(var i=0; i<depth; i++){
        getNestedIndexOfId('...')
}


// full path will be 
indexStacks.join('-')
```

Comment: Wouldn't this suffice? `getFullIndexOfObject = index =>index.replace('item', '');` This looks like this is result you are looking for

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina The item's id is for easier understood, my code has id with `uuid`

Comment: What does the real code look like? Because even if it is but it is still in the format `item__UUID__` this would still be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const items = [
  { id: 'item1',
    children: [
      { id: 'item1-1',
        children: [
          { id: 'item1-1-1' },
          { id: 'item1-1-2' },
          { id: 'item1-1-3',
            children: [
              { id: 'item1-1-3-1'}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { id: 'item1-2',
        children: [
          { id: 'item1-2-1' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { id: 'item2' }
];

const searchIt = (node, search, path = '', position = 0) => {
  if (node.id && node.id === search) {return path !== '' ? `${path}-${position}` : position;}
  if (!node.children) {return false}
  const index = node.children.findIndex((x) => x.id && x.id === search);
  if (index >= 0) {
    return path !== '' ? `${path}-${index + 1}` : index + 1;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
    const result = searchIt(node.children[i], search, path !== '' ? `${path}-${i+1}` : i + 1, i);
    if (result){
      return result;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-1'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-1-1'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-1-2'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-1-3'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-1-3-1'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-2-1'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-1-3-2'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item1-2-2'));
console.log(searchIt({children: items}, 'item3'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an recursive and iterative approach. On found, the path is returned from the most inner object to the outer call of the function.

```js
function getPath(array, id) {
    var result;
    array.some((o, i) => {
        var temp;
        if (o.id === id) return result = `${i + 1}`;
        if (temp = getPath(o.children || [], id)) return result = `${i + 1}-${temp}`;
    });
    return result;
}

const items = [{ id: 'item1', children: [{ id: 'item1-1', children: [{ id: 'item1-1-1' }, { id: 'item1-1-2' }, { id: 'item1-1-3', children: [{ id: 'item1-1-3-1'}] }] }, { id: 'item1-2', children: [{ id: 'item1-2-1' }] }] }, { id: 'item2' }];


console.log(getPath(items, 'item1'));     // '1'
console.log(getPath(items, 'item1-2'));   // '1-2'
console.log(getPath(items, 'item1-1-1')); // '1-1-1'
console.log(getPath(items, 'item1-1-2')); // '1-1-2'
console.log(getPath(items, 'item2'));     // '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using recursion. I have edited my code block and made it into a testable snippet. I had to fix an error in your data (missing comma or something don't remember).

```js
const items = [
   { id: 'itemA',
     children: [ 
      { id: 'item1-1',
        children: [
          { id: 'item1-1-1' },
          { id: 'item1-1-2' },
          { id: 'item1-1-3', children: [ { id: 'item1-1-3-1'} ] },
        ]
      },
      { id: 'item1-2', children: [ { id: 'item1-2-1' } ] },
    ],
   },
   { id: 'item2' }
];


const getItemLevel = (targetKey, item, depth = 0) => {
   if (item.id === targetKey) return depth;
   let foundLevel = null;
   if (item.children) {
     item.children.forEach((child) => {
       if (foundLevel) return;
       foundLevel = getItemLevel(targetKey, child, depth +1);
     })
   }
   return foundLevel;
}

console.log(getItemLevel('item1-1-1', { id:'root', children: items }));
console.log(getItemLevel('item2', { id:'root', children: items }));
console.log(getItemLevel('item1-1-3-1', { id:'root', children: items }));
console.log(getItemLevel('keydoesnotexist', { id:'root', children: items }));
```

Comment: I think this does return just depth of item, not a full path. Please read my question again...Thanks.

Comment: He's already using recursion, but needs to see the parent/child/grandchild relationship.

Comment: ok clearly I don't understand the question then because I read and re-read it, and I am still not getting it. Maybe because his ids are confusing? What's the output you want?

Comment: So like, if you had an item that was id "A" that was the child of "B" that was the child of "C", do you want the output to be "C-B-A"?

Comment: @JSager That items index. Each item is inside an array. So, if the item `item1-1-1` will print `1-1-1` From root to object, every index of its grandfather's index to its index. It's not actual index though, `index + 1` actuaully.

Comment: @Juntae I'm sorry I still don't understand, I think maybe it's a language barrier. If you had A that was a child of B, and B was a child of C, and the id you were looking for is A, what would the output look like?

Comment: @JSager `C index - B index - A index` This is I want. each of A,B,C is inside an its array. right? And they have index. I want to get this index from its root to itself.

Comment: Almost there. By index do you mean the item's id? Or do you mean the depth the index was found at? Like C 3-B 2-A 1? And do you want an array or a string as the final result?

Comment: So if C was the 2nd item in B's children, and B was the fourth item in A's children, and A was the 10th item in the array, you want the output to be C 2 - B 4 - A 10?

Answer (score 0):

a simple way:

```
const recursiveFind = (arr, id, res = {indexes: [], found: false}) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return res

  const index = arr.findIndex(e => e.id === id)

  if (index < 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      res.indexes.push(i+1)
      const childIndexes = recursiveFind(arr[i].children, id, res)
      if (childIndexes.found){
        return childIndexes
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    res.found = true
    res.indexes.push(index+1)
  }

  return res
}

recursiveFind(items, 'item1-1-2').indexes.join('-')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to use Lodash+[Deepdash](https://deepdash.io/#eachdeep-foreachdeep), then:

```
let path;

_.eachDeep(items,(val,key,parent,context)=>{
  if(path) return false;
  if(val.id=='item1-1-2'){
    path=context.path;
    return false;
  }
},{tree:true,pathFormat:'array'});

console.log(_(path).without('children').map(v=>parseInt(v)+1).join('-'));
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/LazbEY?editors=0010) for this